# Time passed till WaitForSingleObject returned

Tags: c++, windows, waitforsingleobject

Is there a way to know how much time passed from when I called WaitForSingleObject function untill it returned?

or that the only way of knowing is by using some kind of a timer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just store current time before calling `WaitForSingleObject()`. Then compare to time when it returns.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725473(v=vs.85).aspx - select a function to retrieve time.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use a timer if you need to track that. The other alternative (although you won't get exact time, a timer would be better) is to call `WaitForSingleObject` with a small timeout value. You can check the return code to see if it is `WAIT_TIMEOUT`. If it is, then increment your time count by the timeout value.

Answer (score 0):

[GetTickCount()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) before and after the call. Watch out for DWORD wrap-around.